# Adding a null or empty value to a combobox at the top of the list

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox

I would like my comboboxes to have the first value be empty so that the user can clear their previous selection. The comboboxes are bound to entities in the ViewModel. So how do I add this first value. I could used `combobox.inert(0, new Entity)`, but is that the correct way?

This is for searching purposes: By default the combobox has no selection and the search will find everything. If they select an item the search is filtered.

Comment: My first idea would be to add a readonly property `IEnumerable myDataPlusAnEmptyRow` to your viewmodel. This property's getter yields first an empty row and then the results of your "real data". Then I'd bind this property to the combobox.

Comment: This is basically how I had it. I just inserted a new Entity and handled the search in the VM. The properties of the new Entity are all null so I just check for that and search accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your ViewModel is responsible for preparing the data to be displayed by the View, the ViewModel should add the empty element at the beginning of the collection that is then bound to the combobox.